# how to save a table when it is created in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g

I gave the command to CREATE TABLE and INSERT the values into the table but its not saved. The next time I login and the table is there but the data inserted is not there. "no selected rows" is the statement shown in screen.
please help to save the changes in ORACLE 11g.

Comment: You probably forgot to `commit` your inserts

Comment: You must read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

First set your Oracle Database client application to always implicitly *commit* or *rollback* transactions before termination (behaviour [recommended](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT016) by Oracle). Then learn about database [transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT1118) and either set your Oracle Database client application in *autocommit mode* or explicitly commit your D.M.L. transactions (with the `COMMIT` statement) because you should not rely on the commit behaviour of a client application.

## Summary on database transactions

*Database transactions* are a fundamental concept of database management systems. The essential property of a transaction is its *atomicity*: a transaction is either

- *committed* (database changes are all made permanent, that is stored on disk); or
- *rolled back* (database changes are all discarded).

Lexically, a transaction consists of one or more S.Q.L. statements of these kinds:

- *data definition language* (D.D.L.) statements (`CREATE`, `DROP`, `ALTER`, `GRANT`, `REVOKE`, …) that change the *structure* of the database;
- *data manipulation language* (D.M.L.) statements (`INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT`, …) that retrieve or change the *contents* of the database.

Database client applications can operate in two different modes:

- *autocommit mode*, where implicit transactions are implicitly started before D.D.L. and D.M.L. statements and implicitly committed on success and rolled back on failure after D.D.L. and D.M.L. statements, and explicit transactions are explicitly started at `BEGIN` statements and explicitly committed at `COMMIT` statements and rolled back at `ROLLBACK` statements;
- *non-autocommit mode*, where mixed transactions are implicitly started before D.D.L. or D.M.L. statements and explicitly committed at `COMMIT` statements and rolled back at `ROLLBACK` statements.

In both modes, transactions are implicitly committed before the database client application terminates normally and implicitly rolled back before the database client terminates abnormally. For database management systems that do not support rolling back D.D.L. statements (Maria D.B., Oracle Database, S.Q.L. Server), transactions are also implicitly committed after D.D.L. statements.

## Explanation

When you issued your `CREATE` statement, since it is a D.D.L. statement and Oracle Database does not support rolling back D.D.L. statements, the transaction that creates the table was implicitly committed. That is why the table structure was still there after you started a new session. But when you issued an `INSERT` statement, since it is a D.M.L. statement and you are not in autocommit mode, the transaction that populates the table was *not* implicitly committed. And as your Oracle Database client application was not set to implicitly commit transactions before termination, that is why the table contents had gone after you started a new session.